# Regex to parse text markup

Tags: regex, parsing, text, styles, markup

I need a regex to parse formatted text with `*bold*` and `_italic_` styles, that can also be combined like `_*bold and italic*_` or `_*bold* and italic_`.

I got the following regex working:

```
([*_])(.+?)\1
```

but it would parse only the outer symbols, leaving the output like this:

> The **bold and italic** text

Explicitly adding a second capturing group seems to do the trick:

```
([*_])((?1))?(.+?)\2?\1
```

but maybe there's a more generic approach that would allow to have an arbitrary number of markup symbols applied at once (e.g. `~_*strikethrough*_~`)?

Also, is it possible to match the format like `_*bold* and italic_`?

Comment: You want the text inside the string to be formatted using HTML or something else? also what language do you use?

Comment: I use swift/iOS, no HTML - just need to parse the input text styles and then apply the corresponding attributes to it.

Comment: I don't know if this can be done in one regular expression, however, it seems like something that would be trivial to do in stages.  First, replace the asterisks.  Then, do another pass and replace the underscores, etc.

Comment: I considered doing it in multiple passes, too, but thought it might be possible to do in a single regex somehow.